# Encode raw PCM to aac using ffmpeg native AAC

Tags: android, ffmpeg, aac

I am trying to convert raw PCM to aac .So i am trying to achieve it through ffmpeg.

My ffmepg configuration

--enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --cpu=armv6 --enable-asm --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --enable-neon --enable-version3 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --ld=arm-linux-androideabi-ld --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D_*thumb*_ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated -marm -march=armv6 ' --disable-everything  --enable-encoder=aac --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-hwaccels --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --disable-demuxer=v4l --disable-demuxer=v4l2 --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2

```
avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_AAC)  find's the AAC encoder succesfully.

audio_context= avcodec_alloc_context()
avcodec_open(audio_context, audio_encoder)  failed to open aac
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is going to be in the ffmpeg portion of the logcat. You should get debug level logging turned on in your ffmpeg libs and capture the log to find out where the codec_open statement is failing.

provide  the log here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ffmpeg inbuilt aac encoder try using libfaac.

First of all cross compile libfaac for android.

in ffmpeg **--extra-cflags** provide path to your compiled libfaac's **include** directory.

in **--extra-ldflags** provide path to your compiled libfaac's **lib** directory.

in ffmpeg `config.sh` use **--enable-libfaac**

Compile ffmpeg again with libfaac.